# Multiple queries in one SQL statement using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to execute a delete statement on multiple tables in my db but for some reason this code isn't working and I'm not sure why. $productId is passed over using a $_GET variable. This statement works in phpMyAdmin but when I get it into my site it stops working. Is the syntax wrong?

```
$sql = '
    DELETE FROM products
    WHERE prod_id = ' . $productID . '
    LIMIT 1;

    DELETE FROM product_category
    WHERE prod_id = ' . $productID . '
    LIMIT 3;

    DELETE FROM product_images
    WHERE prod_id = ' . $productID .'
    LIMIT 1
';

$db->query($sql);
```

Comment: It depends on the API you're using. `mysql` and `PDO` don't allow multiple statements. `mysqli` allows it, but you have to use `mysql_multi_query`.

Comment: Write the 3 queries into a stored procedure.

Comment: @Barmar, mysqli_multi_query* but I'm sure any logical person would figure that out :)

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar said in the comments, PDO doesn't support this.  You can use the mysqli_multi_query but I wouldn't suggest doing it that way.

What I would suggest is using transactions. I don't know what API you are using, but I like PDO so I'll show a basic example with that.

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$q1 = $db->query(...);
$q2 = $db->query(...);
$q3 = $db->query(...);
if ($q1 and $q2 and $q3) {
 $db->commit();
}
else {
 $db->rollBack();
}
```

Why are transactions useful?  It allows you to submit all the queries to the system and then check for any errors and computation of logic before committing it to the system.  If you find any errors, you can rollback() which will prevent any of the above queries from actually modifying the database.